# Terminal not working after Yosemite installation

Tags: terminal, macos

I installed Yosemite now and after the installation the terminal is not working. It used to work before, but after installation of the new OS X on Mavericks it is no longer working. How can I resolve this?

If I open the terminal this message is shown:

```
Last login: Sun Dec 28 00:42:15 on ttys000
login: /usr/local/bin/bash: No such file or directory

[Process completed]
```

Comment: Did you have any trouble during the installation? That could cause it not to be copied back. You may have to reinstall homebrew completely if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You installed another version of bash,right? The default login shell is /bin/bash. you can change it following these steps,

1. go to "System Preferences" > "Users & Groups"
2. click the "padlock" icon and authenticate
3. right-click the icon for your user and select "Advanced Options..."
4. change the value for "Login shell" to "/bin/bash"

Comment: Nice, concise. Go with this one OP.

Comment: Bless you! I thought my OS was a goner...

Answer (score 6):

Your custom installation of `bash` is no longer present after upgrading to Yosemite.

If you [moved Homebrew aside to make the installation of Yosemite go faster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xPGy.png), you can move it back via the Finder and things will work.

Alternatively, you can change the shell used by Terminal.app back to the system-provided `bash` by selecting `Terminal > Preferences` from the menu bar (this should still be available even though the Terminal window shows it failed to start) in the Terminal.app and under the `General` tab set the `Shells open with:` setting to `Command (complete path):` and enter:

```
/bin/bash
```

in to the command area like so:

[image]

This will allow you to open a Terminal window. Once this window is open I **strongly** suggest you set your default shell back to the system-provided `bash` by running:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Once you do this, you can change Terminal.app's preferences back to `Default login shell`.